# Link url_launcher_ios (armv7) ld: framework not found Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Build is successfully working. When I try to create archive, it throws error every time. I am
stuck in this problem for two days. I followed many Stack overflow guides like delete the
folder at flutter path and recopy it. I deleted xcode derived data, then flutter clean and again install pods but again and again same error. I also check many github answers like remove those from "other linker flags" but same.
[image]

Comment: did you do this 

`arch -x86_64 pod install` in your iOS folder?

Comment: no I simply run pod install command in ios folder

Comment: If you have an M1 MacBook, you need to use the arch -x86_64 pod install command.

Comment: My Mac is intel core i5